# How to upload a csv to box folder using powershell

Tags: powershell, export-to-csv, box

i'm new to powershell i have a script running on multiple devices to fetch details and i want a single csv to be generated with those details in a box folder . i wanted to know how to upload a csv to box folder using powershell without hard coding any credentials in script.

Any help will be thankfull.

Comment: Please show us what you have/try so far (see: [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask))

Answer (score 0):

Your question seems more authentication-related than PowerShell syntax-related.

I would first check out the documentation below from Box to get started:

[Automate Box Integration Tasks from PowerShell](https://www.cdata.com/kb/tech/box-ado-powershell.rst)

This link describes how to install the module and use it with these examples:

#### PowerShell

##### Install the module

```
Install-Module BoxCmdlets
```

###### Connect

```
$box = Connect-Box  -OAuthClientId "$OAuthClientId" -OAuthClientSecret "$OAuthClientSecret" -CallbackURL "$CallbackURL"
```

###### Search for and retrieve data

```
$id = "123"
$files = Select-Box -Connection $box -Table "Files" -Where "Id = `'$Id`'"
$files
```

There's a whole getting started guide here [Use Box CLI with OAuth 2.0 | developer.box.com](https://developer.box.com/guides/cli/quick-start/) and chapter 5 focuses on [using Powershell scripts with the CLI](https://developer.box.com/guides/cli/quick-start/powershell-script-templates/)